# MultipleBagFetchException with two hbm.xml files

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using three java objects that are mapped with Hibernate with this pattern :

```
TaskModel.class -> 1:N -> TaskModelPropertiesGroup.class -> 1:N -> TaskModelProperty.class
```

At the project deployment I get this exception :

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

Yes, I've done my homework, I've seen couple of answers about that, but no one about how to modify *hbm.xml* files according.

**1 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)**

Don't know how to change that in my mappings since I am already using `lazy="false"`.

**2 Changing List to Set**

I've tried to change List<> to Set<> inside my classes but I don't think this is the way...

**Here are my mappings :**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModel" entity-name="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModelComplete" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="projects_tasksModels">
    <id name="keyTaskModel">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="description"/>
    <!-- Complete -->
    <bag name="propertiesGroups" table="projects_tasksModelsPropertiesGroups" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
      <key column="keyTaskModel"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModelPropertiesGroupComplete" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModelPropertiesGroup" entity-name="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModelPropertiesGroupComplete" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="projects_tasksModelsPropertiesGroups">
    <id name="keyTaskModelPropertiesGroup">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="keyTaskModel"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="description"/>
    <!-- Complete -->
    <bag name="properties" table="projects_tasksModelsProperties" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
      <key column="keyTaskModelPropertiesGroup"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.spectotechnologies.website.projects.helper.TaskModelProperty" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```